# Return string in Scala without condition

Tags: scala

I have following variables and i want to print output without if else condition

```
val students = StudentService.findAllStudents()
val colleges = StudentService.findAllColleges()
```

i am able to print output in Scala using following code:

```
  students.map(student => {
    val college: Option[College] = colleges.find(college => college.collegeId == student.collegeId)
    if(college.isDefined)
      s"${student.firstName} ${student.lastName} (${college.get.name} ${college.get.location})"
    else
      s"${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}"
  }).foreach(println)
```

is there any way to return result without using if else condition when college is define or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `map` in combination with `getOrElse`:

```
students.map(student => 
    colleges.find(_.collegeId == student.collegeId)
            .map(college => s"${student.firstName} ${student.lastName} (${college.get.name} ${college.get.location})")
            .getOrElse(s"${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}")
).foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness here is a version using `fold` rather than `map`/`getOrElse`

```
students.map(student =>
  s"${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}" +
    colleges.find(_.collegeId == student.collegeId)
      .fold("")(college => s" (${college.name} ${college.location})")
).foreach(println)
```